# Tensorflow cannot allocate memory even though it is available

Tags: python, memory-management, gpu, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am running a CNN on a rig with a GTX 970 with 4gb of VRAM. However, my code gets to the `tf.initialize_all_variables()`, it says that it cannot allocate all enough memory. Here is the exact line:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 625.0KiB.  See logs for memory state. 
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:899] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:334] Executor failed to create kernel. Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
 [[Node: zeros_30 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [160000] values: 0 0 0...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

As you can see, it says that it cannot allocate 625.0 KiB, which the 4gb of the 970 should handle with

Here is the full log, if it is any help:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:924] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.3165
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.52GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:806] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:639] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:656] Bin for 625.0KiB was 512.0KiB, Chunk State: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40000 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40100 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40200 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40300 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40400 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e40500 of size 8192
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e42500 of size 16384
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705e46500 of size 640000
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705ee2900 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705ee2a00 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705ee2b00 of size 1024
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705ee2f00 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705ee3000 of size 51200
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705eef800 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705eef900 of size 73728
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705f01900 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705f01a00 of size 73728
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705f13a00 of size 18432
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x705f18200 of size 15884288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x706e3e200 of size 8192
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x706e40200 of size 33554432
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x708e40200 of size 16384
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:674] Chunk at 0x708e44200 of size 3410411008
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:689]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 10 Chunks of size 256 totalling 2.5KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 1024 totalling 1.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 2 Chunks of size 8192 totalling 16.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 2 Chunks of size 16384 totalling 32.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 18432 totalling 18.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 51200 totalling 50.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 2 Chunks of size 73728 totalling 144.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 640000 totalling 625.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 15884288 totalling 15.15MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 33554432 totalling 32.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:692] 1 Chunks of size 3410411008 totalling 3.18GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 3.22GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:698] Stats: 
Limit:                  3460759552
InUse:                  3460759552
MaxInUse:               3460759552
NumAllocs:                      23
MaxAllocSize:           3410411008

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:270] ******************************************************************************xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 625.0KiB.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:899] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:334] Executor failed to create kernel. Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: zeros_30 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [160000] values: 0 0 0...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I have been ripping my hair out trying to fix this, and I have already reduced the size of my CNN by much too much for my own comfort.

Also, I am running my displays off of my 970... do I need to plug them into the motherboard in order to get the full benefit of my 970?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs:

```
Limit:                  3460759552
InUse:                  3460759552
MaxInUse:               3460759552
NumAllocs:                      23
MaxAllocSize:           3410411008
```

You are maxing out the memory of your GPU already, your model is too big to be processed on that device.